# Object reference not set to an instance of an object error flags when running webform

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to search my database to retrieve some results and populate those to a gridview.

However, I get the above error in the title, and some research hasn't really helped me on why this kind of error flags, and was wondering whether someone with a sharper mind could explain the reason for this error. My code for the code behind file of the specific page is shown below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace StarksComics
{
    public partial class search : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        string b = "";


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBVS"].ConnectionString; // the error occurs at this line. ---- nullreference exception was unhandled by code.

            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
            }

        }

        private void user_chk()
        {
            string a;
            a = TextBox1.Text;

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from tbCharacters where CharName like'" + a + "%'";
            cmd.Connection = con;

            SqlDataReader dr;
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                dr.Read();
                rep_bind();
                GridView1.Visible = true;

                TextBox1.Text = "";

            }
            else
            {
                GridView1.Visible = false;
                b = TextBox1.Text + "is not available in list";
                TextBox1.Text="";
            }
        }

        private void rep_bind()
        {
            string a;
            a = TextBox1.Text;
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tbCharacters where CharName like'" + a + "%'",
                ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBVS"].ConnectionString);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adp.Fill(ds);
            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            user_chk();
        }
    }

}
```

once again, thank you all kindly for reviewing my code. (I've commented out the line, it's just not visible unless you drag the bar, in the page load method.)

Comment: SO primary intent is not to review code. You can post at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Have you tried debugging this and using breakpoints to find what the values of the objects are at certain points in the code?

Comment: Do you know how to debug? Set a breakpoint? If so, which line throws the error? If you do not know how to answer any of the former questions, please learn how to do so

Comment: At what line does the error occur? There are several places where it can happen...

Comment: guys ive added a comment to the line which throws the error, kindly drag it to the right. It's in the page load method.

Comment: try this: ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBVS"];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously it can't find the connection string `DBVS`.

Check your `web.config` whether it exists.

Try this code to check for null on the connection:

```
ConnectionString connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBVS"];

if (connStr == null)
{
    throw new Exception("Cannot find connection string DBVS in web.config");
}
```